# more than one 2d index, not sure which to run geoNear on

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why aggregate

```
    aggregate.near({
      near: coord,
      distanceField: "distance",
      maxDistance: max
    });
```

can return

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "errmsg": "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"more than one 2d index, not sure which to run geoNear on\" }",
    "code": 16604,
    "ok": 0
}
```

having in the scheme the only 2d index:

```
location: { type: [ Number ], index: '2d', sparse: true },
```

more or less when i remove EVERYTHING from the scheme the error doenst change
why? o why...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you remove an index (or even an entire field) in your Mongoose model, it is *not* automatically removed from MongoDB.

Run `db.<your collection name>.getIndexes()` to view all indexes. Make a note of the `name` of the index you want to remove.

Run `db.<your collection name>.dropIndex(<name of the index>)` to remove an index.

By default, Mongoose tells MongoDB to (re-)create indexes ("`ensureIndex()`") when you start your app.